# Why is this .htaccess always 404 redirecting?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products/(bikes|antiques)/?([^/]*)?/?$ $1/index.php?page_id=15&category_id=$2&subcategory_id=$3
```

I'm trying to rewrite

`http://website.com/products/bikes/bike1`

to

`http://website.com/index.php?page_id=15&category_id=bikes&subcategory_id=bike1`

Comment: Confirmed that this is not a RegEx issue so you can remove the tag. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the leading slash from your regex pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^products/(bikes|antiques)/?([^/]*)?/?$ /index.php?page_id=15&category_id=$2&subcategory_id=$3
```

Comment: If the URI will always start with `/products/...`, you can get rid of the `(.*)/` (as @JonLin suggested). If there _could_ be stuff before it, make the / optional: `^(.*)/?products/...`. Remember, the domain name will never show up in the URI.